# Chart, X and Y-Axis labels are blurred in horizontal bar chart using chart.js

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I have horizontal bar chart in which my Y-axis labels are blurred.

I could not understand what was the reason for this. Could some one please help me on this.

PFB is my code samples.

[image]

```
<div style="height: 100% !important; margin-right:0.5% !important; width:32.5% !important; display: inline-block" class="someclass" >
    <canvas id="canTicketCount1" style="height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="height: 100% !important; margin-right:0.5% !important; width:32.5% !important; display: inline-block" class="someclass" >
    <canvas id="canTicketCount2" style="height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="height: 100% !important; width: 33% !important; display: inline-block" class="someclas">
    <canvas id="canTicketCount3" style="height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;"></canvas>
</div>
```

PFB is my Javascript.

```
new Chart(document.getElementById(GraphId), {
                type: 'horizontalBar',
                data: {
                    labels: yAxisValues,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: Title,
                            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                            data: xAxisValues
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: false,
                    //maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: { display: false },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: Title,
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontFamily: "Arial",
                        fontColor: "black"
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                fontSize: 6,
                                fontColor: "black",
                                fontFamily: "Arial",
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                fontSize: 6,
                                fontColor: "black",
                                fontFamily: "Arial"
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved the Issue**

We can't give height and width to canvas in Chart.js. As per below document we should have dedicated div element for Canvas and give height and width to the div element(which i already did, check my code in question).

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#configuration-options

After we should add below configurations for chart.

```
options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
```